# Casting Const to non Const in c

Tags: c, casting

I'm working on a school project in which I need to reproduce many of the C library functions. I'm just struggling with one specific aspect of it.

If you look at the man page for `memchr` you will see that it takes a `const void *` as input and returns a plain `void *`. I would assume that somewhere in the function they are casting from `const` to non `const` for the return variable.

However, when I do this (`clang -Weverything +Werror`) it won't compile. It works without the `-Weverything` tag but I would prefer to use it if possible anyway.

Is there any "correct" way to do this?

Comment: If you find the need to cast a constant to a non-constant, then you're in most cases are doing something wrong. However, in the case of e.g. [`memchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memchr) it's probably needed.

Comment: Can you show us a [MCVE] to demonstrate this case?

Comment: Now for your problem and question, I think it would be better if you rewrote the question to be about the warnings and errors you get. That of course requires you to edit the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as the actual errors you get. And if you haven't done it yet, then please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: C++ provides two overloads: `const void *memchr(const void *, int, size_t)` and `void *memchr(void *, int, size_t)`, because otherwise the function can be used to break `const`. However, C does not allow for overloaded functions.

Comment: Lastly, `-Weverything` is overkill. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` is usually good enough to begin with. With `-Weverything` you *will* get a lot of false positives, warnings that are irrelevant or not needed or just plain wrong.

Comment: Interface-level casting of constant to non-constant is a well-established implementational idiom in C. `strchr`, `memchr` and some other standard library functions are good examples. Learn to use this idiom properly and use it. However, it is not clear what problem you are having since you are not providing any specifics.

Comment: Use a pragma, as you mentioned in one of your comments. It avoids hacks (especially since you're re-implementing standard C functions) and fully documents intent and outcome.

Comment: Don't just tell is it won't compile. Show is, in your question, the exact (copy-and-pasted) error message and the code that triggered it. But the basic problem is that you're trying to do something unsafe (`memchr` should, IMHO, have been split into two functions, one `const`, one non-`const`) and using compiler options that forbid doing unsafe things.

Comment: Sorry, you say _it does not compile_, what do you mean? what's the error message? where's your code?  Please, expose your code **or we will be forced to guess**.

Comment: You need to post your code and the specific error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hack will do it. In practice `sizeof(void *)` is equal to `sizeof(size_t)` on every but the most obscure platforms. Nevertheless, I'd advise against using this. You should drop `-Weverything` instead. Standard C functions date back as far as 70', and the initial C compilers were much less strict than today's Clang or GCC with all of the warnings enabled. The fact that you'll find something "unsafe" in some of them is unavoidable.

```
void * memchr_(const void * ptr_, int c, size_t num);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char ary[] = { 1, 6, 2, 45, 23, 75, 23, 43, 23 },
                  * ptr = NULL;

    ptr = memchr_(ary, 23, sizeof(ary) / sizeof(ary[0]));
    printf("ary = %p, ptr = %p, *ptr = %u\n", (void *)ary, (void *)ptr, *ptr);
    return 0;
}

void * memchr_(const void * ptr_, int c, size_t num)
{
    size_t i;
    const unsigned char * ptr = ptr_;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if(ptr[i] == (unsigned char)c) {
            /* Casting to size_t first so that the compiler doesn't complain */
            return (unsigned char *)(size_t)ptr + i;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks the size_t cast was all it needed. The reason I use -Weverything is because of my OCD but also because some specific things it catches like -Wconversion that is useful to me and not even included in -pedantic.

Comment: Your solution has a problem for byte values above `CHAR_MAX` on architectures with signed chars.  The correct semantics for `memchr` mandate that you write `if (ptr[i] == (unsigned char)c)`

Comment: @user1803425: I would suggest you comment the above code with an extra remark about using `uintptr_t` instead of `size_t`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is unwanted GCC-style (Clang included) diagnostic triggered by the `-Wcast-qual` option in a specific place (`-Weverything` includes `-Wcast-qual`). The solution is to disable *just* `-Wcast-qual` in *just* that place.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-qual"
#endif
    void* non_const_ptr = (void*)const_ptr;
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif
```

A cast to a non-pointer type and back to a pointer type would inhibit all kinds of useful diagnostics wholesale and thus defeat the purpose of `-Weverything`.

`#ifdef __GNUC__` is included for more portability. Some compilers are known to warn about pragmas they don't recognise, unless such pragmas are `#ifdef`ed out.

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly noted, some C library functions must cast their const pointer argument to remove the `const` qualifier for the return value: `memchr`, `strchr`, `strstr` etc. Other standard functions store a pointer to the end of the parsed string into a `char **`, although it points into the array to which they were passed a `const char *`: `strtol`, `strod`...

If your compiler is anal about this and produces warnings, try casting to `uintptr_t` before casting to `unsigned char *`. You can also use a `union` with both pointer types.

The C Standard specifies `memcpy` this way:

> **7.24.5.1 The `memchr` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> void *memchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `memchr` function locates the first occurrence of `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) in the initial `n` characters (each interpreted as `unsigned char`) of the object pointed to by `s`. The implementation shall behave as if it reads the characters sequentially and stops as soon as a matching character is found.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `memchr` function returns a pointer to the located character, or a null pointer if the character does not occur in the object.

If you cannot use other types, you may get away with a cast as `size_t` to suppress the compiler warning, here is a possible implementation:

```
void *my_memchr(const void *ptr, int c, size_t num) {
    const unsigned char *cptr = ptr;

    while (num-- > 0) {
        if (*cptr++ == (unsigned char)c) {
            /* const pointer is cast first as size_t to avoid a compiler warning.
             * a more appropriate type for this intermediary cast would be uintptr_t,
             * but this type is not allowed here.
             */
            return (void *)(size_t)(cptr - 1);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Using `return cptr - 1;` will issue a warning because the `const` qualifier is removed by the implicit conversion to `void *`.

Casting the return value explicitly as `return (void *)(cptr - 1);` should suffice but some compilers still issue a warning to try and help programmers avoid mistakes. Using an extra intermediary cast as `return (void *)(uintptr_t)(cptr - 1);` or `return (void *)(size_t)(cptr - 1);` does not change the semantics of the conversion because `uintptr_t` and `size_t` should be large enough to accommodate a roundtrip conversion between pointer and integer types, and it usually stops the compiler warning.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use data types other that size_t and the built in types unfortunately. Would it be bad practise to use a Pragma to disable that specific check?

Comment: @user1803425: I suppose you could cast the pointer as `(size_t)` which is the same size as pointers on most current architectures, but it is not strictly correct, whereas defining a `union` would be simple and using standard type `uintptr_t` would be correct.

Comment: @user1803425 A pragma is _exactly_ what you should use here. It documents intent, keeps the code completely cross-platform compatible, and allows you to resume the specific const-cast check right after the line that violates it (using `pop`).

Comment: @Qix: pragmas are inherently non portable. The appropriate pragma for clang might cause unexpected behavior for a different compiler, therefore it should be surrounded by appropriate `#ifdef` tests, which makes the whole thing quite ugly.

Comment: @chqrlie true but for exceptions like these, they're just fine. If you want pretty code, the C preprocessor isn't going to help you much.

Comment: "try casting to uintptr_t before casting" can someone explain a little bit more or share a link ? I don't get the mechanism behind. Thanks!

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu: I added an update with a more detailed explanation.